# Virtual Machine Bridge Network on Wifi not working AT OFFICE

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm now experiencing VMs for serving my company project which I need to install and config some application on server.

I need the VM have the same IP subnet as mine so that I can ssh to VM. To achieve that, I need to config VM to has Bridge adapter. It was really frustrating that although I set up bridge correctly as suggestion on the VBox docs, it still didnt worked. I assume it because of VBox, so that I change to using VMWare, but it still didnt work. Suprise, when I try to install VM on another machine which has wired connection, Bridge adapter work perfectly. At that time, I assume it maybe because of my wireless connection (docs said that Bridge networking on wired and wireless has different implementation). I bring my laptop back home, and as you guess, it worked perfectly on both VBox and VMWare. Now, I can say Bridge network is not working because of Wifi at my office.

Can you give me some keywords that I can follow next. I want to understand why this thing(Bridge network not work at specific Wifi) happen? and How can I fix this.

(*) some additional infos:

- My OS is Arch Linux
- Networking on my company is strict, new device wants to have fully connection need to declare IP.

Comment: Because WiFi doesn't by design support bridging. It mandates all frames to have the same source MAC as the one used for association. (I don't remember for certain whether it's only the case of encrypted WiFi though.) Hypervisors like VMWare have NAT-like trick for frames from bridged VMs, while the Linux networking stack doesn't. (It might be possible to partially implement similar trick with nftables.)

Comment: Oh so you are having problems with VMware and VirtualBox. That would be another story then. (I misread that you are switching to qemu/kvm.)

Comment: Btw, you should probably clarify "not working". I assume you normally do DHCP with the WiFi, so did the VM get an address? If not, does static IP make a difference? (Assuming the WiFi does not have any trick that forbid static IP configuration, as in, for example, it works if you do it on the VM host.)

Comment: @TomYan tks for pointing out. "not working" here means that VM doesn't have IP address; I've set static IP for VM as you suggest, and it work. So what do you think of the causing of my problem.

Comment: Well as I said, the hypervisor is actually relying on trick/workaround to get the bridging work for WiFi (basically keeping a IP/MAC mapping table and perform NAT-like MAC change on the frames, AFAIK). Since DHCP needs broadcast to work, which means it needs some extra workaroud of a more or less different approach, and I guess whether that workaround would work depends on the exact configuration/implementation of the specific DHCP server (and client, maybe). I have never read the exact source code, so I don't know what exact criteria it might need.